# Run mathjax on javascript string that is not present in the HTML

Tags: javascript, mathjax

Mathjax typically finds specific elements in the page and specific strings in those elements (substrings delimited by $...$, for example) and alters those strings into nice HTML that looks pretty.

What is the underlying function that MathJax uses to convert those strings into nice HTML?

I would very much like to use that function because I need to run other things on the javascript strings before I actually render them on the page.

Comment: I recommend to read the documentation: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/api/index.html .

Comment: Do you have an idea of where in the documentation this might be addressed?  Also, I am aware that this isn't the "intended" use of MathJax, but it is still worth pursuing in my case.

Comment: You might want to use https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX instead, which provides an API for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is currently not possible as MathJax needs the DOM for its rendering process (e.g. font matching, webfont detection, in some situations measuring dimensions of subexpressions, and worse things on legacy browsers). You can create elements and not attach them before handing them to MathJax (in which case MathJax will attach them temporarily) but that comes with a small risk of CSS interfering.

FWIW, we're planning to work on a more or less DOM-free rendering next year (since recent browser engines are more stable in terms of layout); cf. mathjax-node.

Disclaimer (I guess) I'm a member of the MathJax team.

Comment: That's not a disclaimer, it's a recommendation!

Comment: Thanks and looking forward to it!  :)

Comment: @Peter Krautzberger Has this feature come out yet?  And if so could you provide a link to the relevant docs?

Comment: [MathJax v3](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-v3) is in public alpha right now. It still uses the DOM by default to construct output but it no longer requires the context of the page, cf. [this demo](https://mathjax.github.io/mj3-demos/mj3-tex2html-global.html). You can also use something other than the usual DOM APIs by replacing the relevant utility, cf https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-dev/Y0U4Ig0hbrA.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-render the contents on a page, say the user has typed some expression such as `$\frac{a}{b}$` and it is displayed literally as $\frac{a}{b}$ you should use `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);` to run the mathjax renderer again and process the page contents.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt.  Unfortunately, this does not answer the question and this is specifically the solution that I do not want.  I want to run Mathjax on a string that is *not* present in the HTML.